# Based on what factor does heat transfer between two bodies of different masses at different temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

If two spheres have charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ and radii $R_1$ and $R_2$, when made to contact, charges flow between the two spheres until their potentials are the same. Initial potentials, $V_1=\frac{KQ_1}{R_1}$ $V_2=\frac{KQ_2}{R_2}$ and lets say a net $x$ amount of charge flows from one sphere to the other. Then to find $x$ we equate the new potentials $V_1' = V_2'$ and we come to the following equation and easily find $x$ like so:$$\frac{K(Q_1-x)}{R_1}=\frac{K(Q_2+x)}{R_2}$$
Similar to this, instead of charges if we were given temperature and instead of radii, we were given mass, then how will we proceed? If two bodies with mass $M_1$ and $M_2$ at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$, were brought in contact, how will I find the net temperature of the two bodies? Just like how we can say that the potentials must be same upon contact in electrostatics, what factor must be same here?

Comment: Sounds like an assignment. Do you have any thoughts yourself?

Comment: It's not. I was solving a question and I came about this thought.  @Pieter

Comment: In some engineering contexts, there is the term "thermal mass".

Comment: In freshman physics, did you learn about the concept of "heat capacity," the amount of heat it takes to change the temperature  of a body by a certain amount?